# List view with Group By date column problem

Tags: list-view

I have a list with a date column. If I create a list view with "Group on this date column (ascending)" with number of groups to display to 10 (or less than item count in list).

Then the view does not list the newest dates on the top. The first 11 list items that shows in the left picture is not grouped at all.

Please see picture for details:

[image]

Any help/suggestion is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the field type that you are using for the date column? It doesn't look like a date/time column. If its text then that will be the issue because text sorts differently to date/time.

Comment: It is a date column: http://i48.tinypic.com/6hrmdt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is gone after upgrading to [December 2012 Update](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff800847.aspx)